# Oracle Sequences exclude specified number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to create a sequence with excluded specified number so that sequence variable does not create specified numbers.
I am able to create sequence using following sql statement

```
CREATE SEQUENCE s_test;

CREATE SEQUENCE s_test2
START WITH 10 INCREMENT BY 5
MINVALUE 10 MAXVALUE 20
CYCLE CACHE 2 ORDER;
```

The reason why I need this usage is that, some tables are created and used before using sequence and ths IDs of table is lets say  2,5,99,101. It means that id 1,3,6...98,100 could be used and I dont want them not usable by staring sequence from 102.

I just want to know how to create some exclude number sets.

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/905417

Comment: why do you care if 1,3,6... are skipped?  Just start at 102.  Nobody should expect sequences to be dense (moving forward, you can still get gaps in the numbers due to caching, etc)

Comment: it is a case and I expect to find a solution. Eventually we are talking about Oracle which is as complex as any Operating System.

Comment: How do you exclude values from a sequence?  With difficulty.  Oracle sequences are not designed for gap-free values; stopping an instance will "lose" values in cache but not yet used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `start with` option lets you start at any particular number you like -- skipping numbers along the way.

You could create your own user-defined function to return the values that you want.

Or, when the `nextval` of the sequence is a number you want to skip, then you can skip the value using something like:

```
alter sequence seq_name
increment by 124;
```

This would be possible in an insert trigger, for instance, where the sequence is used to populate an `id` value.

However, I question why you would want to do this.  The values from the sequence would normally be meaningless numbers used for an id.

EDIT:

Then use a before-insert trigger to check if `nextval` is already in use.  If so, just increment past that value.